# SerializeValue not working with a FixedString32Bytes value

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I have the following code:

```
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Netcode;

public struct NetworkString : INetworkSerializable
{
    private FixedString32Bytes info;
    public void NetworkSerialize<T>(BufferSerializer<T> serializer) where T : IReaderWriter
    {
        serializer.SerializeValue(ref info);
        

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return info.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator string(NetworkString s) => s.ToString();
    public static implicit operator NetworkString(string s) => new NetworkString() { info = new FixedString32Bytes(s) };
}
```

The error say:

> 'Unity.Collections.FixedString32Bytes' cannot be used as parameter of
> type 'T' in generic type or method
> 'BufferSerializer.SerializeValue(ref T,
> FastBufferWriter.ForPrimitives)'.  no conversion boxing of
> 'Unity.Collections.FixedString32Bytes' a 'System.IComparable'.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/nullable-types-for-networklist-networkvariable.1269746/) `FixedString32Bytes` does not work anymore :

> Using ForceNetworkSerializeByMemcpy is currently the way to go starting from this release. We're looking at bringing back the old behaviour which allowed for just using fixed string on its own.

Use the following struct to bypass this issue (cf [NEOMORPH_STUDIO_SRL](https://forum.unity.com/threads/fixedstring32bytes-not-serializable-after-networkstring-implementation.1289057/)):

```
using System;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Netcode;

public struct NetworkString : INetworkSerializable
{
    private ForceNetworkSerializeByMemcpy<FixedString32Bytes> data;

    public void NetworkSerialize<T>(BufferSerializer<T> serializer) where T : IReaderWriter
    {
        serializer.SerializeValue(ref data);
    }

    public override string ToString() => data.Value.ToString();

    public static implicit operator string(NetworkString networkString) => networkString.ToString();
    public static implicit operator NetworkString(string s) => new NetworkString { data = new FixedString32Bytes(s) };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like what magicletur said, and if you can't initialize the network variable / list, try changing the class to `public struct NetworkString : INetworkSerializable, IEquatable<NetworkString>`